# Custom Container border in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

> Hello friends I am new don't know how to make a custom border kindly help me to generate this type of border.
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAlwG.png

Answer (score 1):

Adding a border to a widget is very easy in Flutter. We just need to wrap the widget in a Container and add BoxDecoration to it.

Let’s say we want to make a square with blue borders all we need to do is:

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: Text('mrflutter.com'),
  ),
),
```

Also in the link there are other types

[Source](https://mrflutter.com/how-to-add-borders-to-a-widget-in-flutter/)

Also there is a tutorial about BoxDecoration widget
[Boxdecoration tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyPhSsim8p4)